# Metro & StreamBuffer namespace error - am I understanding this correctly?

Tags: java, namespaces, java-metro-framework, stax, wsit

All,
  I'm (still) working on calling a WSE 3.0 .NET web service from Java/Metro 2.0.  We've got the security requirements set so that we're encrypting the body & header of the messages & signing the headers.  I'm able to send a request to their service & get a response, but Metro is unable to validate the signature & throws an error from the WSIT code.  I got the latest WSIT code from CVS & here's a code snippet of the method that's blowing up:

from com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.GenericSecuredHeader:

```
private XMLStreamBuffer completeHeader;
public void writeTo(XMLStreamWriter w) throws XMLStreamException {
        try {
            // TODO what about in-scope namespaces
            completeHeader.writeToXMLStreamWriter(w);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new XMLStreamException(e);
        }
    }
```

**As you can see, there's a TODO in there, that I think indicates that the method can't handle the situation I have, but I'm not sure I know what they mean by 'in-scope' namespaces.**

Here's the snippet of XML from the web service response that it's breaking on:

```
<wsa:Action wsu:Id="Id-46282a5d-c7fa-403c-8ac9-f7df0dfdb0cf">
http://someAction</wsa:Action>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" />
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />

<Reference URI="#Id-46282a5d-c7fa-403c-8ac9-f7df0dfdb0cf">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
<DigestValue>
/2ivNKDpYSLqPWHzrSxN/RuZ/e8=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
```

In the stack trace (included below), it complains about not being able to validate the reference URI="#Id-46282a5d-c7fa-403c-8ac9-f7df0dfdb0cf".  **What I'm unclear on is - is it failing because the Reference element doesn't have a namespace attribute or prefix?**  **Should they be allowed to inherit the namespace from the parent Signature element, or can the StreamBuffer classes not handle that?**

To contrast, here's a similar XML snippet from my request (generated by WSIT), where the ds prefix is

xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ns10="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
xmlns:ns11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-secureconversation/200512" 
xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity" Id="_1">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse S"/>
</ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>

<ds:Reference URI="#_5002">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
<exc14n:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="S"/>
</ds:Transform>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>
vtf9n+OcI1nT0exavD4/ZQy6jm8=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
```

When Metro generates these blocks, everything has a namespace prefix.

If you're still reading this far - thank you!  Here's some snippets from the stack trace:

```
Error occurred while trying to cache START_ELEMENTcom.sun.xml.stream.buffer.stax
.StreamReaderBufferProcessor$InternalNamespaceContext
[16:12:54.026] WSS1759: Following error null occured while performing canonicali
zation null
[16:12:54.026] javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.GenericSecuredHeade
r.writeTo(GenericSecuredHeader.java:303)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.StreamWriterData.wr
ite(StreamWriterData.java:101)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Exc14nCanonicalizer.t
ransform(Exc14nCanonicalizer.java:153)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Transform.transform(T
ransform.java:182)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Reference.transform(R
eference.java:183)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.crypto.dsig.Reference.validate(Re
ference.java:102)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.processor.SignedInf
oProcessor.processReference(SignedInfoProcessor.java:422)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.processor.SignedInf
oProcessor.processReferences(SignedInfoProcessor.java:385)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.processor.SignedInf
oProcessor.process(SignedInfoProcessor.java:189)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.Signature.process(S
ignature.java:206)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.h
andleSecurityHeader(SecurityRecipient.java:466)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.c
acheHeaders(SecurityRecipient.java:281)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.ws.security.opt.impl.incoming.SecurityRecipient.v
alidateMessage(SecurityRecipient.java:223)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.verifyInboundMess
age(SecurityTubeBase.java:462)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processClientRe
sponsePacket(SecurityClientTube.java:412)
[16:12:54.026]  at com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.processResponse


javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: WSS1722: Error occurred while validating Reference with URI: #Id-46282a5d-c7fa-403c-8ac9-f7df0dfdb0c
f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, I believe that my initial understanding of this is correct.  the Metro/WSIT code that calls the StreamBuffer code to stream the XML from the SOAP Response can't handle that elements that don't have namespace prefixes or attributes.  I've submitted an issue against WSIT, for those that are interested in the follow-up:

https://wsit.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1423

Comment: Can you give me the solution regarding the issue? [Please check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696160/error-while-serializing-timestamp-element-occured-while-performing-canonicalizat)